# App Crashing after taking more than 6 pics using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera in iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller, didreceivememorywarning

I am using Camera in my application ,the app is crashing after taking more than six pics and the crash log is `Memory warning received`. I am saving image like,

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
   // Save image
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo, nil);
[imagesArray addObject:image];
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You aren't releasing the memory used by the images when you are done with them. This means memory is filling up and you are running out of space. Then the app crashes

Comment: I am releasing the image there itself,still it is crashing

Comment: All I see is an addition to an array, that would INCREASE the retain count.

Comment: use autoreleasepool and check it. By your code, it increases retainCount of image and you are not releasing image anywhere.